podman can not connect to container port
I run postgresql with podman :
> podman run \
    -d \
    --name=postgresql \
    -v /opt/Docker/volumes/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    -e POSTGRES_DB=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=adminpass \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    postgres:latest

why i can not connect to port from host ?
> psql -U admin -W -h 127.0.0.1 admin

this is podman network :
> podman network ls
NETWORK ID    NAME        VERSION     PLUGINS
2f259bab93aa  podman      0.4.0       bridge,portmap,firewall,tuning

i receive this error on postgres log :
> podman logs -f postgresql 
2024-04-09 15:41:01.784 UTC [29] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.0.2.100", user "admin", database "admin", no encryption

postgres port on host machine:
netstat -nltpua 2> /dev/null | grep -i 5432
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      146245/containers-r

exactly same of that commands work on docker engine . but i can not understand why does not work on podman ?!

I tried your commands on fedora 39 (with podman 4.9.4) from a normal unprivileged user account. The psql command prompted me for the password and I was able to log in to the postgres server.

I found problem :
My host is Ubuntu 22.04 .
podman create rooless container . so volumes should be owned by host user .
actually i try to run container with this command :  (sorry i should write complete command, Question Updated)
> podman run \
    -d \
    --name=postgresql \
    -v /opt/Docker/volumes/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    -e POSTGRES_DB=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=adminpass \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    postgres:latest

docker by default engine fix permissions of /opt/Docker/volumes/postgresql .
but with postman this directory should be owned by host user .
> chown $USER:$USER /opt/Docker/volumes/postgresql    
> # now run :    
> podman run \
    -d \
    --name=postgresql \
    -v /opt/Docker/volumes/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    -e POSTGRES_DB=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=adminpass \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    postgres:latest   

or simply create volume with podman :
> podman volume create postgresql
> podman volume inspect postgresql 
[
    {
        "Name": "postgresql",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mountpoint": "/home/$HOME/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/postgresql/_data",
        "CreatedAt": "2024-04-09T22:58:49.8317138+03:30",
        "Labels": {},
        "Scope": "local",
        "Options": {}
    }
]
> podman run \
    -d \
    --name=postgresql \
    -v postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    -e POSTGRES_DB=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=admin \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=adminpass \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    postgres:latest    

